# Simple VB ststment deconstruction

Tags: excel, vba

Could somebody please explain this simple vba statment to me? I just want to know what each part is referring to, and basically what this statement is accomplishing within my workbook. Thank you

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Bren Template'!R[-3]C[-6]"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a cell reference.  In the ActiveCell (the one chosen), it will put the formula `='Bren Template'!R[-3]C[-6]`.  The formula breakdown is "Bren Template" is a reference to a sheet with that name.  The R[-3] refers to three rows ABOVE the active cell.  The c[-6] refers to three columns to the LEFT of the active cell.

So, if the active cell is H5 that formula will read `='Bren Template'!B2`
If your active cell is I6, then the formula will read `='Bren Template'!C3`

Note: The r[-3] and c[-6] will be "translated" from R1C1 style (i.e. Row 1 Column 1) when the formula is actually set in the cell.